# Need to make a flag if chatbot question is answered?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a flag for the questions that were answered. Below is a sample data frame.

```
userid  message                    type
1        hi                        incoming
1        how may I help you        outgoing
1        looking for a job         incoming
1        whats your name           outgoing
1        nitin                     incoming
1        kansal                    incoming
1        whats your age            outgoing
2        hi                        incoming
2        how may I help you        outgoing
3        hi                        incoming
3        how may I help you        outgoing
3        looking for a restaurant  incoming
3        can you suggest something incoming
3        whats your name           outgoing
```

So, now the outgoing questions that got an incoming question by the same user id
would have a flag. Output dataframe would look like.

```
userid  message                         type          got_response
    1        hi                        incoming          
    1        how may I help you        outgoing           1
    1        looking for a job         incoming
    1        whats your name           outgoing           1
    1        nitin                     incoming
    1        kansal                    incoming
    1        whats your age            outgoing           0
    2        hi                        incoming
    2        how may I help you        outgoing           0
    3        hi                        incoming
    3        how may I help you        outgoing           1
    3        looking for a restaurant  incoming
    3        can you suggest something incoming
    3        whats your name           outgoing           0
```

Looking for a numpy based solution. I have done this using for loop but the real database has millions of rows, so it takes hours to complete the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Flag'] = ((df['userid'] == df['userid'].shift(-1)) & (df['type'].eq('outgoing') & df['type'].shift(-1).eq('incoming')))
```